# Link mysql Table to current user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 tables: **wp_users** and **CD2015_EmailIncidents**. I've made a query in phpmyadmin.

Thats joins both tables by email and creates a table with the following fields:

```
Email - Reference - Type - Site
```

what I would like to do is when a user logs into the members area the table only displays their data.

so filtering the table to current_user email to the table

heres the code i have but its display all data:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Site, Type, Reference, Email
FROM CD2015_EmailIncidents AS s
JOIN wp_users AS c
ON s.Email = c.user_email 
WHERE c = '<?php $current_user->user_email ?>' "); 
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
echo "Reference"."  "."Site"."  "."Type"."<br><br>";
foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo $row->Reference."  ".$row->Site."  ".$row->Type."<br>";
 }
?>
```

any help would be amazing!...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Am I getting closer??

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Site, Type, Reference, Email
FROM CD2015_EmailIncidents 
JOIN $current_user->user_email 
ON CD2015_EmailIncidents.Email= $current_user->user_email ");


echo "Email:"."  "."Type:"."<br><br>";
foreach($result as $row) {
echo $row->Email." ".$row->Type."<br>";
}
?>
```